# Date column not ordering correctly

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that i use to paste some information, the issue is that since i am pasting it and since the order from where i copy is in reverse (the newest from top) when i paste it i need to order it.
For some reason that i am not understanding it will not order it automatically, any idea why ?
I have already change the format of the column to the correct one, but even with that is not ordering correctly.

Any idea why and how to fix it with out messing with the sheet data... ?

This is an example of the sheet: [sheet example here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Epri0XhM5FmonpWrrT3vv4Fm3tnRzoFYstZObgGggrQ/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why

The datatype of the values is plaintext instead of date and Google Sheets is not able to automatically interpret the values as dates due to the comma.

## How to fix

To fix this you could...

### Before copying and pasting

When generating the date values, avoid to include the comma

### After copying and pasting

Choose one of the following:

1. Use find and replace to remove the comma.
2. Use an auxiliary column with a formula like this:

   ```
    =ArrayFormula(datevalue(substitute(A:A;",";""))+TIMEVALUE(substitute(A:A;",";"")))
   ```
3. Use Google Apps Script.

Comment: HI, well everything is a plain text but them again that is why there is an option to format the text type (in this case it's formatted to date using a specific prefix "Full_day Short_mounth_wordy Full_year, Full_hour:Full_minutes:Full_seconds") . The weard thing is that on excel the same thing happen and i think it should not but yehh will try your solution thanks...

Comment: but yehh it indeed works has you saying... But why has a plain text and formated correctly to date does not work ?

Comment: Well you saying it's because of the comma and i have not try copy and paste with out it but in that case on the format prefix to use it should not allow to place a comma there, but it allows so i suppose it should work even with comma... I guess i will work with a hidden column that will use the formula you gave to order or maybe a javascript code (not sure yet). Either way thanks for the help and for the explanation.